# PL/SQL concatenating data

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, syntax-error

I'm having a problem with concatenating my PLC/SQL procedure what went wrong with my code, what foundation should i do?

```
IF iReceiptTotal > 0 THEN
    @con := ' AND a.MUNC_ID = ' || "'" ||iMuncID ||"'" ||' AND TO_DATE(IF(' ||"'" ||iManual || "'" || "='AUTO'," ||'a.TPAY_ISSUED_DATE, a.MANUAL_COLLECTION_DATE),"'"yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss"'") <= TO_DATE(SYSTIMESTAMP(),'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss am') AND TPAY_CANCELLED_STATUS = ',"'0'", ' AND TPAY_NO_PAYMENT = ',"'0'", ' ORDER BY LOC_NO LIMIT ', xLimit);
ELSE
    @con := ' AND a.MUNC_ID = ' || "'" ||iMuncID ||"'" ||' AND TO_DATE(IF(' ||"'" ||iManual || "'" || "='AUTO'," ||'a.TPAY_ISSUED_DATE, a.MANUAL_COLLECTION_DATE),"'"yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss am"'") <= DATE_FORMAT(SYSTIMESTAMP(),"'"yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss"'") AND TPAY_CANCELLED_STATUS = ',"'0'", ' AND TPAY_NO_PAYMENT = ',"'0'", ' ORDER BY LOC_NO LIMIT ', xLimit);
END IF;
@q := 'UPDATE tbl_tax_payment a SET a.BCS_TYPE= ' || "'" ||xType ||"'" ||',a.BCS_NO = ' || "'" ||xBCS ||"'" || ', a.BCS_COUNTER= ' || "'" ||xMax ||"'" ||' WHERE a.RECEIPT_TYPE =' ||"'" ||iReceipt ||"'" || ' AND a.LOC_NO IS NOT NULL AND a.BCS_NO IS NULL AND a.RCO_CODE = ' ||"'" ||iRCO ||"'" || @con;
                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  @q;
                        DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;
```

> Here's my Error
>   the symbol @ was ignored
>   PLS-00103:encountered the symbol "yyy/mm/dd/ hh24:mi:ss" when expecting characters... like4 likec between member submultiset.

What does it means?

Comment: `@q` is not a valid variable name in PL/SQL. Please read the manual

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `"'"yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss"'"` to `''yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss''`.

Similarly you have to change all `"'"` to `''`.

*Queries Edited*

```
IF iReceiptTotal > 0 THEN
   @con := ' AND a.MUNC_ID = ' || '''' ||iMuncID ||'''' ||' AND TO_DATE(IF(' ||'''' ||iManual || '''' || '=''AUTO'',' ||'a.TPAY_ISSUED_DATE, a.MANUAL_COLLECTION_DATE),''yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'') <= TO_DATE(SYSTIMESTAMP(),''yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss am'') AND TPAY_CANCELLED_STATUS = ',''0'', ' AND TPAY_NO_PAYMENT = ',''0'', ' ORDER BY LOC_NO LIMIT ', xLimit);
ELSE
   @con := ' AND a.MUNC_ID = ' || '''' ||iMuncID ||'''' ||' AND TO_DATE(IF(' ||'''' ||iManual || '''' || '=''AUTO'',' ||'a.TPAY_ISSUED_DATE, a.MANUAL_COLLECTION_DATE),''yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss am'') <= TO_DATE(SYSTIMESTAMP(),''yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'') AND TPAY_CANCELLED_STATUS = ',''0'', ' AND TPAY_NO_PAYMENT = ',''0'', ' ORDER BY LOC_NO LIMIT ', xLimit);
  END IF;
  @q := 'UPDATE tbl_tax_payment a SET a.BCS_TYPE= ' || '''' ||xType ||'''' ||',a.BCS_NO = ' || '''' ||xBCS ||'''' || ', a.BCS_COUNTER= ' || '''' ||xMax ||'''' ||' WHERE a.RECEIPT_TYPE =' ||'''' ||iReceipt ||'''' || ' AND a.LOC_NO IS NOT NULL AND a.BCS_NO IS NULL AND a.RCO_CODE = ' ||'''' ||iRCO ||'''' || @con;
                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  @q;
                        DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;
```

Comment: i changed it but still i have an error PLS:00103 encountered "," symbol.. do i need to change my "'" character to what format? or something else?

Comment: `@con` is not a valid variable in PL/SQL

Comment: actually the stored procedure i've used is based from MySQL procedure i'm migrating it to the Oracle PL/SQL.. so it means i need to assign it to an another variable, am i right?